# Rails, Devise - send user back after submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When user adds products to his cart it is not mandatory for him to be logged in. But when he goes into created cart and hits *"Checkout"* I check if he is logged in:

```
<%=
    link_to_if(current_user.nil?, "Checkout", new_user_session_path) do
     link_to( "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get)
   end
%>
```

So if not logged in, I redirect to new_user_session_path. Problem is that after logging in he is being redirected to index_path. And I want him to be redirected back to his cart. The same with logging up.

I am using Devise, so should I generate Devise controllers and do it from there? How that should be done?

Note: I am using module for current cart:

```
module CurrentCart

  private

    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
  end
```

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos

Comment: Serioga, (no)thanks for minus. But link is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     #place your route here
  end
end
```

Comment: My try was:   `def after_sign_in_path_for(cart)
    redirect_to @cart and return
  end` But got `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise::SessionsController#create` error...

Comment: But this copy/paste from link sent by that other angry guy, made the job:   `after_filter :store_action

  def store_action
    return unless request.get? 
    if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
        request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
        request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
        request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
    end
  end`

Comment: just copy this method don't use any filter  for that  in this method you put you r code like your give method this is devise method

Comment: also refer this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: but without :after_filter it does not work... Anyway thanks for great advices!